# Jquery ui slider range not working in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

Jquery ui slider range change event is not working in IE browser

```
$("#borrow_field").on('change', function(){
    alert('yes');
     var brCurrentValue = $("#slider-range").slider('option', 'value');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#slider-range").slider("value", brCurrentValue);
    },200);
});
```

I had used the callback function in slider also, but not working

Comment: check out this  -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279372/jqueryui-sliders-not-working-on-ie

Comment: i seen this before itself. still not working

Comment: Can you provide a demo of the issue?

Comment: If you're hinting that this is browser-specific why are you not including the version? And please provide some HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7hLLr33/).

```
$("#slider-range").slider();
$("#borrow_field").on("change", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#slider-range")

      .slider("value",
        $("#borrow_field").val()
      );

  }, 200);
});
```

I'm assuming you're trying to do update both ways, where you can update the borrow field based on the slider value, and update the borrow field manually (which should be reflected in the slider - and is perhaps what your javascript is meant to do).

In which case, you were not getting the input value properly.